# Map validation problem in QGIS 2.18

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2, validation

There is a problem in map validation for prediction purpose in QGIS 2.18 (validate the simulated map with the actual map). It showed an error message `error occurred while executing python code.` I have added the screenshot. Please, suggest me to overcome the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the main error message. (Click `Stack Trace` button)

Comment: I know it's not the topic, but you should upgrade to QGIS 3.16. QGIS 2 is not maintained anymore by QGIS.org since January 2019.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I found that the different geometry between simulated and reference map. How to solve this problem?